# Delete folder with specific condition

Tags: script

I need a script to delete a folder, only if the folder does not contain media files with extension `avi` or `mp4`.

Comment: What type of script do you want to write? AppleScript, Automator workflow, or shell script?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about shell scripting and not specific to Apple software or hardware. This question would be better answered on superuser or another Stack Exchange site.

Comment: I'd say its fine here whatever script is called for. Our users might be more likely to answer with other options but we'd only migrate if the op asked.

Answer (score 1):

If all folders to be removed are directly under the containing folder and all mp4 and avi files are directly under the kept folders:

`for d in */;do ls "$d"|grep -Eq '.*\.(mp4|avi)$'||echo rm -r "$d";done`

If the mp4 and avi files can be in subfolders of the kept folders:

`for d in */;do [[ $(find "$d" -iname \*.mp4 -o -iname \*.avi) ]]||echo rm -r "$d";done`

If the folders to be removed can be in subfolders of the containing folder:

`find . -type d|while read d;do ls "$d"|grep -Eq '.*\.(mp4|avi)$'||echo rm -r "$d";done`